# Executar um UPDATE no MySQL apenas quando o número de rows for igual a 1

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

Como fazer um **UPDATE** apenas ser executado quando o número de rows que retornou for igual a 1 em uma **única query apenas com sintaxe SQL** utilizando o exemplo abaixo?

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT count(*) AS rows FROM exemplo WHERE id_usuario = 100;

if (rows == 1)
{
    //executar UPDATE
}
```

Comment: A tabela que você quer atualizar é a mesma cujo número de rows você precisa checar?

Comment: Sim e não. Preciso utilizar em 2 ocasiões na qual em uma é na mesma tabela e na outra não. Bem pensado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) me parece o ideal aqui.

Caso a tabela que você queira utilizar *seja diferente* da tabela cujo número de rows você precisa checar pode fazer algo similar a isto:

```
UPDATE tabela2 SET campo=
   CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM exemplo WHERE id_usuario=100) = 1 THEN 
     'novovalor' -- novo valor para "campo" 
   ELSE 
     campo -- atualiza "campo" com o valor de "campo", nada muda
END;
```

Caso a tabela alvo do update seja a mesma cujo número de rows deve ser checado a coisa é mais complicado já que o MySQL faz alguma loucura interna que não permite você referenciar diretamente a mesma tabela do update na inner query do select, mas ainda é possível com um pequeno truque:

```
UPDATE exemplo SET campo=
   CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM (
      SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE id_usuario=100
   ) AS aliasqualquer) = 1 THEN 
     'novovalor' -- novo valor para "campo" 
   ELSE 
     campo -- atualiza "campo" com o valor de "campo", nada muda
END;
```